# Git error: 'Refusing to lose untracked file' when doing merge

Tags: git

I have some files on a folder which I didn't want git to track, so I added them to the `.gitignore` like so:

```
Directory/Build/
```

but when i was using `git status` they were still shown as "modified files not staged for commit". I looked this up and it was suggested to clean the git index using:

```
git rm --r --cached Directory/Build/
```

I did this, and after `git status` all the files that I wanted to have untracked were shown as `Deleted: file`, I thought this was good enough as they will be deleted from the working tree (but not locally I think?).

But then when I tried to do `git pull` I got some weird merge conflicts that I do not know how to resolve:

```
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'Directory/Build/..../file.class'
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'Directory/Build/..../file.jar'
```

and also some

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): ...
CONFLICT (modify/delete):  Directory/Build/..../file.jar deleted in HEAD and modified in <<id>>. Version <<id>> of Directory/Build/..../file.jar left in tree.
```

I tried to do `git merge -Xours` but it still gave me the conflict.

How to resolve?

Comment: As [VonC says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618504/1256452), you need to get the files out of the way. The reason `-Xours` and `-Xtheirs` have no effect is that these are what I call "high level" (commit-wide) conflicts, but the two `-X` options only direct Git to prefer one side or the other when resolving "low level" (inside-one-file) conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

You still need, after the `rm --cached -r`, to:

- commit those deletions
- move the build folder out of the way (outside the git repo): a `git status` must show a clean working tree for the next command to run,
- `git pull --rebase` (to replay your local commits on top of the upstream branch)
- move the Build folder back in

Answer (score 0):

If you have added some files to Git they are tracked also if you write them to your gitignore. So you have to remove them first. With:

```
git rm --cached files
```

then the files are deleted in your repository but they will keep local. Then you can write it to gitignore and they will be ignored.

If you run the comment the files are shown first as deleted because you have done exactly that. So add add and commit the changed. Then it should work. After that you shouldn't get some new untracked files in your directories.